# エディタ(Atom)からTeratermにcloneしたデータを見る方法

Tags: atom-editor, teraterm

サーバ上にクローンしたファイルを、エディターから開くには何をすればいいのでしょうか？

Web上で共有しているファイルを、tera termにcloneしました。
そのファイルの中身をローカルのAtomから、編集できるようにしたいです。
Windows10です。

サーバ　エディタ　連携
で検索かけたところ、FTPやSFTPというワードがてきてそれぞれ検索したのですが、まだリテラシーが低いため関係性が理解できませんでした。

ご教授ください。

--追記--
FTP接続が有力そう...ですかね[FTP](https://wa3.i-3-i.info/word1137.html)

--コメント受けての追記--
ターミナルにcloneしただけだとviなどでファイルの編集は可能ですが、ローカルにあるatomだと編集できないという認識までは合っているのでしょうか？
コマンドやpowershell上に落とせばローカルのファイルからGUIとして見れますよね？
ですが、今回はIPアドレスを打ち込んでSSH接続しているTeratermからなので、（cloneしたもの自体がまだサーバー上にありローカルではないから？、）Atomでは開けない

初めて複数人で作業をするためgitを使用するの流れ自体曖昧で失礼します。
既に共有のブランチがブラウザ上にあり、それをIPアドレスでサーバに接続したTera term上にcloneしました。

Comment: `teraterm` は単なるターミナルなので「 `teraterm` にクローン」というのも読者に通じないです。なんだか [XY 問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/3060) のような気がしてきました。普通に開発する際に ftp を使うとかまずありえないです。こうするといいかもしれないと自分が勝手に解釈したことでなく、真にやりたいことを書いていただいたほうが良い回答が付くでしょう。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

やりたいこと、質問の環境が

・(gitでクローンした)編集したいファイルがリモートのサーバ上に置いてある
・自身はローカルPC(Windows)上で作業をしている
・ローカルPCのAtomエディタからリモートのファイルを編集したい

だろうという前提で。いくつか方法が考えられます。私自身はAtomエディタを使用していないので、詳しい解説はできませんが、考えられる代わりの方法も含めてざっくりと紹介しておきます。

#### リモートとローカルでファイルの同期を行う

既に調べられた方法がこちらになります。Atomエディタであれば「Remote-FTP」というパッケージをインストールすることで、FTP/SFTP経由で編集対象のファイルをローカル・リモート間で同期してくれるようです。

#### リモートのファイルをWindowsから直接参照する

サーバ側がどんなOSで何が動いているのか分かりませんが、一般的なWindowsやLinuxであれば「ファイル共有」の仕組みを利用してローカルPCから直接参照する方法もあります。ただし事前にサーバ側でSambaなどのファイル共有の設定をしておく必要があります。

#### ローカルPCにもgitで同期を行う

サーバ上にgitで同期しているのであれば、同じファイルをローカルにもgit経由で同期してしまうという手もあります。二度手間にはなるかもしれませんが、他の方法ではやりたい事の本筋から外れる分野の知識も必要になってきます。
gitコマンドが使えているのであれば、とりえあずはこの方法が手っ取り早い気もします。

---

蛇足ですが、TeraTermはあくまでサーバ上の操作を行うための「画面」に過ぎないので、乱暴に言うとただのブラウザのようなものと思ってください。

Comment: なるほど、詳細ありがとうございます。teratermを、リモート、ローカル、クライアント、サーバなどの言葉に分類できずいました。とりあえずFTPで現在試そうとしているのですが、一つの方法として合っていることが分かってよかったです。ありがとうございます。